# Loop in trigger SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have below trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DeleteUserData]
ON  [dbo].[site_users]
AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--delete user uploads
update my_gallery set deleted=1 where un=(select un from deleted) and subdomain=(select subdomain from deleted)

--delete user pms
delete from pms where toUn=(select un from deleted) and subdomain=(select subdomain from deleted)

--delete friends
delete from friend_blocked_list where  un=(select un from deleted) and subdomain=(select subdomain from deleted)
```

END

it works fine when i delete one user but if i delete more than one users subquery returns more than one user in deleted table and trigger fails.

how can i adjust it so that it works when i delete more than one user at a time?

I have thought about altering it as below. Is it correct way?

Altered

```
--delete user uploads
update my_gallery set deleted=1 where un in (select un from deleted) and subdomain in (select subdomain from deleted)

--delete user pms
delete from pms where toUn in (select un from deleted) and subdomain in (select subdomain from deleted)

--delete friends
delete from friend_blocked_list where  un in (select un from deleted) and subdomain in (select subdomain from deleted)
```

Some may ask why don't you add Foreign keys to tables but usernames unique within their subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is one way. It won't handle NULLs values in the sub queries though but I think this won't matter.

You can also use [EXISTS (handles NULLs) and JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance) (an SO question on EXISTS/IN/JOIN)

Please note: SQL is designed to handle multiple rows anyway...