# How to improve this query. Sending data is too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT COUNT(`t`.id) 
FROM `product` `t` 
INNER JOIN `category` `c1` ON ( `c1`.id ='15' )
LEFT JOIN `category` `c2` ON ( `c2`.`parent_category_id` = '15' ) 
LEFT JOIN `category` `c3` ON ( `c3`.`parent_category_id` = `c2`.`id` ) 
LEFT JOIN `category` `c4` ON ( `c4`.`parent_category_id` = `c3`.`id` ) 
LEFT JOIN `category` `c5` ON ( `c5`.`parent_category_id` = `c4`.`id` ) 
LEFT JOIN `category` `c6` ON ( `c6`.`parent_category_id` = `c5`.`id` ) 
LEFT JOIN `category` `c7` ON ( `c7`.`parent_category_id` = `c6`.`id` ) 
WHERE 
t.category_id IN (c2.id,c3.id,c4.id,c5.id,c6.id,c7.id) 
AND (t.mod='Accepted')
```

I have a category and product table, category table has parent_category_id which refers to the  same category table but indicates that record is sub category.

```
    SHOW PROFILE Result (ordered by duration)

state   duration (summed) in sec    percentage
Sending data    1.69029 99.96392
freeing items   0.00015 0.00887
statistics  0.00015 0.00887
checking query cache for query  0.00009 0.00532
init    0.00006 0.00355
preparing   0.00003 0.00177
checking permissions    0.00002 0.00118
optimizing  0.00002 0.00118
Opening tables  0.00002 0.00118
System lock 0.00001 0.00059
starting    0.00001 0.00059
cleaning up 0.00001 0.00059
Table lock  0.00001 0.00059
end 0.00001 0.00059
executing   0.00001 0.00059
logging slow query  0.00001 0.00059
Total   1.69090 100.00000

Change Of STATUS VARIABLES Due To Execution Of Query

variable    value   description
Bytes_received  291 Bytes sent from the client to the server
Bytes_sent  72  Bytes sent from the server to the client
Com_select  1   Number of SELECT statements that have been executed
Handler_read_key    133514  Number of requests to read a row based on a key
Handler_read_next   133549  Number of index columns read with a range constraint or an index scan
Key_read_requests   444695  Number of MyISAM key blocks read from cache
Key_reads   234 Number of MyISAM key blocks that were read from disk. Indicates insufficient key cache size
Key_write_requests  200 Number of MyISAM key blocks that were written to cache
Key_writes  105 Number of MyISAM key blocks written to disk. Indicates insufficient key cache size
Last_query_cost*    19845567    The total cost of this query as computed by the query optimizer
Open_files* 1475    Number of files opened
Qcache_free_memory* 149209104   Amount of Query cache free memory
Qcache_hits 1520    Number of queries served directly by the Query Cache
Qcache_inserts  190 Number of queries inserted into the Query Cache
Qcache_not_cached*  2062788 Number of queries that were not cached by the Query Cache. They are not cacheable or was not cached due to the query_cache_type setting
Questions   1   Number of statements executed by the server
Table_locks_immediate   574 The number of requests for table locks that could be granted immediately
Threads_cached  6   The number of threads in the thread cache
Threads_running*    3   The number of threads that are not sleeping
* Actual values after query execution (not changes due to query)

EXPLAIN Result

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  c1  const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  t   ref category_id, mod    mod 2   const   48  Using where
1   SIMPLE  c2  ref parent_category_id  parent_category_id  5   const   18  
1   SIMPLE  c3  ref parent_category_id  parent_category_id  5   ucuzolur.c2.id  7   
1   SIMPLE  c4  ref parent_category_id  parent_category_id  5   ucuzolur.c3.id  7   
1   SIMPLE  c5  ref parent_category_id  parent_category_id  5   ucuzolur.c4.id  7   
1   SIMPLE  c6  ref parent_category_id  parent_category_id  5   ucuzolur.c5.id  7   
1   SIMPLE  c7  ref parent_category_id  parent_category_id  5   ucuzolur.c6.id  7   Using where
```

You can find the profile above. As you see everything is fine except sending data is too slow. This query is just a count query, why sending consume too much time and how can I improve this query. I have 20000 rows in category table.

Comment: A product can belong to a category at any level, not just the leaf level? And what is the goal of the query? To find how many products belong to the category structure of Category 15?

Comment: Yes a product can belong to any category at any level except master. The goal of the query is to find the count of products in Category 15's subs. Imagine: Category 15 (Master) -> subs -> subs_subs -> subs_subs_subs and the products may be in subs or subs_subs or subs_subs_subs... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your goal correctly, rather than creating the whole category structure, you could try using subqueries to drill downwards to find all products that belong to the Category 15 structure.

Simplified SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 'product' 't'
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM 'category' 'c1'
    WHERE 't'.'category_id' = 'c1'.'id'
        AND ('c1'.'id' = 15
        OR (EXISTS
            (SELECT *
            FROM 'category' 'c2'
            WHERE 'c2'.'parent_category_id' = 'c1'.'id'
                AND ('c2'.'id' = 15                    
                    OR (EXISTS .... 
                        recursion here depending on 
                        how many levels the categories can have)
            )
        ))
    )
```

This may also behave horribly, but it may also make better use of indexes perhaps, or reduce the number of hits to the category table.

**Attempt 2**

Does the following behave any better?

```
SELECT COUNT(`t`.id) 
FROM `product` `t` 
    LEFT JOIN `category` `c2` ON ( `c2`.`id` = t.category_id )
    LEFT JOIN `category` `c3` ON ( `c2`.`parent_category_id` = `c3`.`id` ) 
    LEFT JOIN `category` `c4` ON ( `c3`.`parent_category_id` = `c4`.`id` ) 
    LEFT JOIN `category` `c5` ON ( `c4`.`parent_category_id` = `c5`.`id` ) 
    LEFT JOIN `category` `c6` ON ( `c5`.`parent_category_id` = `c6`.`id` ) 
    LEFT JOIN `category` `c7` ON ( `c6`.`parent_category_id` = `c7`.`id` ) 
WHERE (`c2`.`id` = 15
    OR `c3`.`id` = 15 
    OR `c4`.`id` = 15
    OR `c5`.`id` = 15
    OR `c6`.`id` = 15
    OR `c7`.`id` = 15)
AND (t.mod='Accepted')
```

Making sure that parent_category has an index of course.

Comment: `c2.id = 15` is wrong here because c1.id=15 already. t.category_id must be c2.id. I correct this and try but in the first subquery mysql try to use all rows (20000) because of all the where parameters are binded to another table and I cannot filter the rows with a where parameter.

Comment: I have 'c1'.'id' = 15 OR EXISTS.... So either c1 is 15, or its parent is 15, and so on.    But what is actually missing is 't'.'category_id' = 'c1'.'id'  Adding that now.

Comment: @OnurErenElibol Added an "Attempt 2" for you to check out.

Comment: I did first approach and is acceptable with 0.9 sec. This is not enough but I think that is the fastest approach I can use. I will try the second one now.

Comment: second attempt didn't give the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have indexes on the columns you're joining and try not to use 'WHERE IN'.

@Quassnoi makes a very good point with his answer:
[SQL JOIN vs IN performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance)