# Need a select query to get the output as shown below.?

Tags: mysql

How to fetch plate_number which apeear multiple times in column

database:numbers

table name:number_plate

```
plate_number
45990
54667
45990
0908
54667
65534
3422
0908

output:
45990
45990
54667
54667
0908
0908
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324107/show-all-duplicated-rows This will help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one would give you recurring plates and number of occurrences

```
select  plate_number, count(*) 
from    table
group by plate_number
having count(*) > 1
```

To have the exact output you wrote, you should join the query above with the table again

```
select  t1.plate_number
from    table t1
join    (
            select  plate_number
            from    table
            group by plate_number
            having count(*) > 1
        ) t2
on     t1.plate_number = t2.plate_number
order by t1.plate_number
```

Comment: select  plate_number
from    table
group by plate_number
having count(*) > 1

Comment: you can write like this also

Comment: Can u please help:How to colour(red) 6,7,8  number from database

$number=$row['plate_number'];

ex:
89786
74867
1687
86767
56786
78611
78686

i wanted to colour 786 countinues or 6,7,8 only single digit should red not multiple digits in the case 78686 it should red first 786 remaining 86normal colour

Comment: You should really ask a new question, so that you can explain it better