# how to get duplicate values from a mysql query on input of array?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query for which I am giving a list of items as input, the item list contains duplicate values.

```
select * from ITEM  where ITEM_NUMBER in ('15','41', '15','41');
```

the resulting output contains 2 rows with

> ITEM_NUMBER 15

and

> 41

I want a query, which returns 4 rows with duplicate values.

Comment: Use a `left join` instead of `in`.

Comment: Use set collection to store values. Then iterate set create query text

Answer (score 0):

This is one option using join:

```
select *
from items a
join (select item_number
      from items  
      group by  item_number
      having count(*) > 1) b
on a.item_number = b.item_number;
```

Adapted from an answer in this link:
[Show all duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324107/show-all-duplicated-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using UNION and TOP

```
select * from 
(select top 2 * from item where item_number=15) 
union all select * from 
(select top 2 * from item where item_number=41);
```