# translating sql sub query to join

Tags: sql, subquery

I had a long query, I short it out by using joins instead and resultant query is as below but still it has sub query. How to convert this sub query to join

```
SELECT 
    pav.post_id as Id, img.path as Path, attr.name as Name, pc.title as Category, pav.value_text as Valuess, post.created_on as createdOn 
FROM 
    postings post inner join post_attributes_values pav on post.post_id = pav.post_id
    left outer join images img on post.post_id = img.post_id and img.sequence='1' 
    inner join attributes attr on pav.attr_id = attr.attr_id 
    inner join categories_parent_categories pc on attr.cat_id = pc.category_id 
where 
    pav.post_id in  (select distinct post_id from post_attributes_values where value_text = 'SFX')
```

Comment: Is distinct necessary? Do you search for specific attribute with value 'SFX' or any attribute will do?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: The design of table is like that distinct is necessary.

Comment: Distinct shouldn't be nessessary in the sub query because you are just checking for in....

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for dropping the subquery?

Comment: @BobVale: replacing sub query with join to improve performance

Comment: @Sandy if this is MS Sql using `where exists (select post_id from post_attribute_values where value_text='SFX' and post_id=pav.post_id)` should be one of the faster performers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your last comment to Matei's answer I have come to realize that you actually want *ALL the posts* where one of the attributes has value of 'SFX'. If I understood correctly, your only alternative is to add derived table and join by post_id:

```
SELECT pav.post_id     AS Id,
       img.path        AS Path,
       attr.name       AS Name,
       pc.title        AS Category,
       pav.value_text  AS Valuess,
       post.created_on AS createdOn
FROM   postings post
       INNER JOIN post_attributes_values pav
               ON post.post_id = pav.post_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN images img
                    ON post.post_id = img.post_id
                       AND img.sequence = '1'
       INNER JOIN attributes attr
               ON pav.attr_id = attr.attr_id
       INNER JOIN categories_parent_categories pc
               ON attr.cat_id = pc.category_id
       INNER JOIN
       (
             SELECT DISTINCT post_id
             FROM   post_attributes_values
             WHERE  value_text = 'SFX'
       ) sfxPosts
               ON pav.post_id = sfxPosts.post_id
```

(Query reformatted thanks to [instant sql formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm).)

Comment: will there be any performance improvement by replacing sub-query with derived table?

Comment: @Sandy [This man explained it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance). It also depends heavily on your sql engine; there is no silver bullet. Best is to test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this? Please test it

```
SELECT 
    pav.post_id as Id, img.path as Path, attr.name as Name, pc.title as Category, pav.value_text as Valuess, post.created_on as createdOn 
FROM 
    postings post 
  inner join post_attributes_values pav on post.post_id = pav.post_id AND pav.value_text = 'SFX'
  left outer join images img on post.post_id = img.post_id and img.sequence='1' 
  inner join attributes attr on pav.attr_id = attr.attr_id 
  inner join categories_parent_categories pc on attr.cat_id = pc.category_id
```

Comment: `pav` is mentioned twice. You might want to remove last occurrence.

Comment: I already have tried this but returned rows are not as expected.

Comment: What's wrong? give me please an example of rows which are returned and what should be returned instead