# How to display rows which don't match a row in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display staff that are not ward managers.

I have this query which displays ward managers:

```
SELECT Name, Grade, WardManager, StaffNo  
FROM STAFF, WARD   
WHERE WARD.WardManager = STAFF.StaffNo;
```

However I can't figure out how to display the staff who aren't ward managers. I have tried a combination of IS NOT, NOT LIKE, NOT IN etc and none of them seem to work.

Comment: What are the types of the columns?

Comment: I don't see any reason for this to not be possible if the data types are same. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand you table structure correctly, but when someone complains that `NOT IN` returns no rows, it's almost always a problem with NULL values in the column used for the `IN` operator.

Try this one:

```
select *
from staff
where staffno not in (select wardmanager 
                      from ward 
                      where wardmanager IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: @henry: see here for a more detailed explanation: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx (it's SQL Server syntax but the basic logic is the same)

Answer (score 0):

To give an alternative to a_horse_with_no_name's answer this can also be done with a `left outer join`:

```
select s.*
  from staff s
  left outer join ward w
    on s.staffno = w.wardmanager
 where w.wardmanager is null
```

This works be joining on what you want but then asking for values that do *not* match.

As to which is quicker / more efficient [it depends on your specific circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance) so you would have to test both and see.

As there is no, relevant, data in the `ward` table ( all columns will be null ) there is no point selecting columns from this table. However, the benefit of a `join` is that you can, if you want. Say, for instance, you removed the `where` clause you could return staff that are ward manager's and staff that are not. The differentiation being that columns from `ward` would always be null when they are not a manager.

Yet another method of doing this is using `where exists`, but like `not in` this will only be suitable if you do not want to return any columns from `ward`.

```
select s.*
  from staff s
 where not exists ( select 1
                      from ward w
                     where wardmanager = s.staffno )
```

Once again speed and efficiency is determined by your circumstances and how many rows there are in the tables.