# NOT IN not work in my query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables `data` and `page`, in `data` table I have some records, and some `data` records id will be store in `page` table.

Now I want select `id` and `title` form `data` table which is not on `page` table.
So I wrote this query :

```
SELECT d.id,d.title
FROM data AS d, page AS p
WHERE d.id NOT IN (p.data_id)
ORDER BY d.title ASC
```

this query will work, but when `page` table is empty this query cannot restore records !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    data a
        LEFT JOIN page b
            ON a.ID = b.data_id
WHERE   b.data_id IS NULL
ORDER   BY a.title ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74fcd/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*empty page table*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dbde/1)

Comment: [SQL JOIN vs IN performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance)

Answer (score 2):

Here is it with subquery, but without join:

```
SELECT id, title
FROM data
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT data_id FROM page)
ORDER BY title ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The NOT IN will give you what you want but depending on your database system (and the type of indexes) this will not be the best (fastest) solution. More often then not EXISTS will be faster. But your mileage may vary.

Give it a try:

```
SELECT id, title FROM data
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM page WHERE page.data_id = data.id)
ORDER BY title ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to determine what `data` does not have a `page`:

```
SELECT d.id, d.title
FROM data d
WHERE d.id NOT IN (
    SELECT data_id FROM page
)
ORDER BY d.title ASC;
```