# Ask about Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have table like this:

```
CreateDate  |  UserID
2012-01-1   |     1
2012-01-10  |     2
2012-01-20  |     3
2012-02-2   |     4
2012-02-11  |     1
2012-02-22  |     2
2012-03-5   |     3
2012-03-13  |     4
2012-03-17  |     5
```

I need the query to show UserID which created after 1 February 2013 and not exist in database befor 1 February 2013

From the above example the result must be:

```
CreateDate  |  UserID
2012-02-2   |     4
2012-03-13  |     4
2012-03-17  |     5
```

Can it resolved only in single query without Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
select 
  CreateDate,
  UserID
from Users
where CreateDate >= '2012-02-01'
and UserId not in (
  select UserId
  from Users
  where CreateDate < '2012-02-01'
)
```

SqlFiddle link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7efae/2

Comment: Ahhh... Damn... Stupid Brain...... Thank you for your help....thats the answer I need......

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery which separately gets the `UserID` which exist before `Feb. 2, 2013` and the result of the subquery is then joined back on the table itself using `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  UserID
            FROM    tableName
            WHERE   CreateDate < '2013-02-01'
        ) b ON a.userID = b.userID
WHERE   a.CreateDate > '2013-02-01' AND
        b.userID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e51df/6)

for faster performance, add an `INDEX` on column `userID`.

- [SQL JOIN vs IN performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance)

Comment: Yess.... this work to..... hmmm now which one is better query for a table with lots of data. Should I use Left Join or SubQuery in WHERE ?

Comment: If you have properly define index on the table then you don't have to worry about performance.