# Using MySQL return data as input for 2nd query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a 'news feed' of sorts, and I'm having trouble writing up the query in order to do this!

The question in a nutshell, if User A goes to their home page and follows Users B, C, D - I'm trying to make it so that they see content from users B, C, D.

Assuming 2 tables: `posts, connections`

Where table `posts` has lots of relevant columns, and table `connections` has columns `id,user,followed`

In (terrible) pseudocode, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author=(SELECT followed FROM connections WHERE user='A')
```

And it'd post stuff by B,C,D (aka who A follows)

By any chance would anyone know how to write this as an actual MySQL query? The stuff I've read already seems pretty confusing, and I don't really understand how I would go about doing this!

Thank you, very much! Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You mean a subquery, such as: SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM t2); Check out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: what are the structure of each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   posts 
WHERE  author IN (SELECT followed FROM connections WHERE user = 'A')
```

or `JOIN` (*which I preferred*)

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    posts a
        INNER JOIN connections b
            ON a.author = b.followed
WHERE   b.user = 'A'
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the IN method, but why do you prefer JOIN? Thank you! :)

Comment: [JOIN Clause vs. IN Clause](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/940-SQL-Optimization-Case-Study-JOIN-Clause-vs-IN-Clause.htm) and another one is here [SQL Join VS IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance)

Answer (score 1):

Use a join:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM connections c
JOIN posts p
  ON c.followed = p.author
WHERE user='A'
```

Note that the `connections` table is listed first, so an index on `user` could be used driven by the where clause.