# comma separated values or table variable in case of using IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we want to pass an array of values as a parameter to an SP in which it is used as values in IN clause.

Which one is better in case of performance :

1- Passing values as comma separated string

ie

```
Select * FROM myTable WHERE Id IN (@myConcatenatedValues)
```

OR

2- Passing values as a table variable consist of a column that holds this values as rows

ie

```
Select * FROM myTable WHERE Id IN (Select Id from @myVariableTable)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance

Comment: @Secret Squirrel : you are right but my question was about IN clause specifically not JOIN or EXISTS or something else.

Comment: if you pass comma separated string, then you have to use prepared statement in your stored procedure. But if have those values already existing in a table, it will be better if you pass table variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a quick test run of this using the below 3 queries:

```
DECLARE @UsersInString VARCHAR(255) = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10'

/* Prone to SQL Injection, do not use like this! Sanitise your inputs */
EXEC (' SELECT * FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE UserID IN ( ' + @UsersInString + ' ) ')
GO
```

and:

```
DECLARE @UsersInTable TABLE (
    UserID INT
)

INSERT INTO @UsersInTable
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[User] U
JOIN @UsersInTable UT ON UT.UserID = U.UserID
```

and:

```
DECLARE @UsersInTable TABLE (
    UserID INT
)

INSERT INTO @UsersInTable
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[User] U
WHERE U.UserID IN (
    SELECT UserID
    FROM @UsersInTable
)
```

The actual execution plan returned indicates that the top query is faster in my case; the  query used a `Clustered Index Seek` only.

The middle query was marginally slower as along with the `Clustered Index Seek` it also used a `Table Scan` on the table variable.

The bottom query was even slower as along with the `Clustered Index Seek` and `Table Scan`, it also performed a `Sort` on the table variable; one would assume in an attempt to optimise the `IN ()` query against the sorted Clustered Index.

However it is largely dependent on the indexing of the column being queried; along with how long it would take to build the string or table variable.

A fairly important side note: Passing the values as a comma separated string could be risky; you would have to dynamically construct the `IN ()` statement using string concatenation; which could leave you open to SQL Injection.

Comment: what about using IN (not using join) on second scenario ?

Comment: Added a third query to my answer bud

Comment: Is there any additional difference in using the table variables if you include an index in their definition? `declare @severities table (SeverityId uniqueidentifier unique clustered)`