# Exception query - Miss-match from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two Tables that I would like to run exception on.

Table 1 `'Retail'`

Columns in Retail is as follows.

```
Branch_Name, Customer_Name, Document_Number
```

Table 2 `'Doc'`

```
Branch_Name, Customer_Name, Invoice_Number
```

Now document number and Invoice number is the same thing.

what I want the query to show me is, how many records do we not have in Doc that is in retail.

Example.
'Retail'

```
Branch_Name, Customer_Name, Document_Number
sat             BOSS           s11121
bat             Kiven          s25456
```

Table 2 `'Doc'`

```
Branch_Name, Customer_Name, Invoice_Number
sat             BOSS           s11121
```

Result

We are missing,

```
Branch_Name, Customer_Name, Invoice_Number
bat            Kiven         s25456
```

thank you

Comment: Select Branch_Name, Customer_Name, Document_Number from Retail where Document_Number  not in
(
Select Invoice_Number from Doc
)

Answer (score 1):

The following will produce all rows from `Retail` and only those record that don't have a corresponding/identical row in `Doc`.

```
select *
from Retail r
  left outer join Doc d on r.Branch_Name = d.Branch_Name
    and r.Customer_Name = d.Customer_Name
    and r.Document_Number = d.Invoice_Number
where d.Branch_Name is null;
```

Comment: I suggest you add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better

Comment: The question/request specifically asked for a query. I'll add a note to explain though...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select retail.* from doc where Retail left join doc on Document_number =Invoice_Number where Document_number is null
```

Comment: No offence, as far as I know IN operator is faster when unique id is selected. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance  and http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/22/sql-server-better-performance-left-join-or-not-in/

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the two table using left join and pick up the columns which are null in Doc table like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Retail r LEFT JOIN DOC d
ON   r.Branch_Name = d.Branch_Name
AND  r.Document_Number = d.Invoice_Number
WHERE d.Invoice_Number IS NULL
```