# SQL Select item which has same value in all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, if the below is the table

```
SupId    ItemId          Status
1        1               Available
1        2               OOS
2        3               Available
3        4               OOS
3        5               OOS
4        6               OOS
5        7               NULL
```

I am looking to fetch distinct suppliers whose `all items` are OOS or NULL.

One solution is to get all the suppliers who has atleast one active item (active suppliers) and then add a clause `NOT IN` active suppliers to pick non active supplier.

Is there any better way to achieve the same?

Comment: Maybe convert `NOT IN` to `JOIN`?

Comment: @qxg, can you explain the issue with NOT IN vs JOIN and how the perf is taken into consideration.

Comment: Do you want suppliers for which _all_ are `NULL` or _all_ are `OOS`?  Or, do you want to restrict to just those two values?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance. Have a try of all approaches and let execution plan tell you the truth.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen suppliers for which all are NULL or all are OOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, using aggregation:

```
SELECT SupId
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY SupId
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'OOS' OR Status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*) AND
    (MAX(Status) = 'OOS' OR COUNT(Status) = 0);
```

This assumes you want suppliers who have *only* all `NULL` or all `OOS` status.  If you just want to limit to both these two status values, then use this:

```
SELECT SupId
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY SupId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Status <> 'OOS' AND Status IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SupId FROM my_table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM my_table
                 WHERE SupId = t.SupId
                   AND [Status] IS  NOT NULL 
                   AND [Status] <> 'OOS')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SupId 
FROM Table 
WHERE SupId <> (
                 SELECT DISTINCT SupId 
                 FROM Table 
                 WHERE Status NOT IN ('OOS',NULL)
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.supid = t.supid and t1.status <> 'OOS');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `group by` and `having`:

```
select suppid
from t
group by suppid
having (min(Status) = 'OOS' and max(Status) = 'OOS') or
       min(Status) is null;
```