# How to merge two SQL SELECT where the second one returns multiple records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables **Assignment**, **Student** and **StudentAssignment**.
Assigement table have two columns `AssignmentID` and `AssignmentName` and in Student Assignment table i have `StudentID,AssignmentID`. I am trying to write a query which looks something like this:

```
Select * 
from Assignment 
where AssignmentID = (Select AssignmentID
                      from StudentAssignment 
                      Where StudentId=@studentID)
```

I get an error saying:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.

Please help me model the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to return the details of *every* assignment a student has done, you need to use `IN` instead of `=`:

```
Select * 
from Assignment 
where AssignmentID IN (Select AssignmentID
                       from StudentAssignment 
                       Where StudentId=@studentID)
```

Comment: Can you throw some light on JOIN vs IN ?

Comment: @Arpit in what regard?

Comment: @Arpit with Join one will get duplicate records if there is 1 to many relationship exists with the joining table

Comment: So same can be achieved via JOIN, so some light on pros cons of each approach but not sure if question needs that.

Comment: @Arpit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `=` with `IN`

```
Select * 
from Assignment a
where AssignmentID in (Select AssignmentID
                      from StudentAssignment s
                      Where s.StudentId=a.studentID);
```