# Between these two SQL queries, is one of them 'correct'?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in the process of teaching myself SQL queries.  My question arrives from w3resource.com sql exercise 6 in the sub-query set of questions.  To summarize the question, we want a query that displays the commission of the salesmen serving customers in Paris.  Here are the two tables with their columns given:

---

**Salesman**(salesman_id, name, city, commission)

**Customer**(customer_id, cust_name, city, grade, salesman_id)

---

Below are two queries that I wrote that achieve the solution in different ways.  My question is if there is a more 'correct' one out of the two?  With 'correct' taking into account performance, standards, etc.  Or are both equally fine?  I ask because I imagine as I continue with more complex queries, should I be sticking to one for performance/versatility reasons?
Thanks

```
select commission from Salesman
where salesman_id IN
(select salesman_id from Customer
where city = 'Paris')
```

```
select commission from Salesman
join Customer on (Salesman.salesman_id = Customer.salesman_id)
where Customer.city = 'Paris'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance

Comment: also you should try explain plan for both the queries so you will know how mysql interprets them..

Comment: The queries produce different results. In case there are multiple Paris-customers with same salesman, you will get that salesman's comission multiple times in the second query.

Answer (score 2):

They're both fine.

In terms of style, both have their advantages, e.g.

- Using the IN clause simplifies the main SQL query (from a readability point of view) since you don't have to do a join. If you have several other joins it's nice to reduce them as much as possible to keep track of what's going on.
- Using the JOIN is needed if you had a composite key instead of a single salesman_id.

They might generate different query plans depending on your database, but like with most code it's better to start by writing for readability & maintainability and optimise only the bits you need to. There's not going to be any difference for this sort of thing.